# Message error after deleting all rows (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

I have made a program that fetch data from a database and show a table with different rows.

The problem is when i want to delete every single row in the table :/

After deleting all rows in a table i got this error:
[image]

Here is my home file:

```
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record->id."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carrera."</td>
                      <td>".$record->nombre."</td>
                      <td>".$record->descripcion."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carga_horaria."</td>
                      <td align='center'>
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/edit')."/$record->id'> 
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDIT</button></a> |
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/delete')."/$record->id'> 
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button></a>

                  </tr>";
        }
    ?>

</tbody>
```

Here is my controller file (with index and delete functions)

```
    class Home extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();

         $this->load->model("Crudmodel");

    }
    public function index(){

        $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();

        $this->load->view('home', $data);

    }
    public function delete($id){

        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('materias');

        redirect('Home/index');

    }
```

Model file:

[image]

Dont know what to do :S

Comment: `$this->Crudmodel->getRecords()` doesn't return an array, check you return with `var_dump()`

Comment: Plz add model file..

Comment: What?, do not understand you pal :S

Comment: I already edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you have `$records` before looping through them:

```
if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {

  foreach($records as $record) {

    // the rest of your code
  }

}
```

Comment: No way pal, i got this error:
https://i.gyazo.com/4b645a1dba1c8cf7434031c52d4fd3d9.png

Comment: I have updated my answer check it an tell me what u get

Comment: I have tried using the same code.. now it is working pal.Thank you very much!:)

Comment: How can i contact you dude?

Comment: So the previous one is working or that? `https://twitter.com/AmrAly57` twitter account

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to use "&& $records != false", now it is working :).
Gonna contact you dude!:D, stay sharp!

Comment: mate, i send you the same comment because they "remove" the last conversation :/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171291/codeigniter-login-system-issue-loging/43171499#43171499

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do simply,

```
if ($records) {
  foreach($records as $record) {
    // the rest of your code
  }
}
```